# NuGet - download .dll with debug info and .pdb file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

Is it possible to set NuGet to download .dll files with debug information and .pdb files in VS 2010?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the public nuget gallery the intention is to use [SymbolSource.org](http://www.symbolsource.org/)

David Ebbo [The easy way to publish NuGet packages with sources](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/04/easy-way-to-publish-nuget-packages-with.html)

If you're using an internal nuget repository, you should be able to just include the PDBs in the appropriate `<files>` configuration in the .nuspec